# Eclipse constantly removes src/it from souce folders

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm using `maven-failsafe-plugin` to run integration tests which are stored in the `src/it` source folder. But eclipse constantly removes it from `.classpath`.

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/it">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Does somebody face the same issue? How can I fix this problem?
I'm using `Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
<attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
```

sounds like that `classpathentry` is being placed there by the pom or the maven plugin for eclipse. That would mean that each time your project is refreshed or the pom is being read again, this entry would be overwritten.

Can you remove that attribute?